# Get nltk on all python versions

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, nltk

After a lot of trouble I have managed to get nltk 2.0.4 on my computer (I used to have the newest version). The problem now is that it's only installed with one version of python on my computer (python 2.7.6). I also have python 2.6, and I need nltk on this version to. Is this possible? I have tried to just copy the file that has nltk in the python 2.7 folder into the 2.6 folder, but this didn't work.

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far. Did you try `pip install nltk==2.0.4`?

Comment: I tried this first, but got the impossible python setup.py egg_info error. Then I tried to update setuptools and download ez_setup.py, but this didn't work either. I ended up just downloading the nltk-2.0.4 zip file and running setup.py inside this folder. This worked in a sense, since I godt nltk 2.0.4 in python 2.7, but not in 2.6...

Comment: what error did you get when you tried on 2.6?

Comment: If i try to import nltk in 2.6 I get: ImportError: No module named yaml. When I go to the folder where 2.6 is stored there is no nltk folder/files.